# React router dom v6, I have this bootstrap pop up model where I allows the user to do a search and click on the element found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I have a pop-up bootstrap model, this pop-up has search functionality which allows the user to search and click on the item.

But when the user clicks on an item while still on the page of another item, I want the application to load the item using the id of the item.

what I expect:

1. the user clicked on the search button from the left navbar
2. Pop-up displayed with input and items
3. Searched and found
4. The user is clicked on the item
5. The application takes the user to that item using the id of the item
6. Again, the user wants to make another search while still that item page
7. then takes the user to that searched item page

Actual result :

1. the user clicked on the search button from the left navbar
2. Pop-up displayed with input and items
3. Searched and found
4. The user is clicked on the item
5. The application takes the user to that item using the id of the item
6. Again, the user wants to make another search while still that item page
7. Is taking the user to a page that doesn't exist

I know the problem is the way I'm using the react-router, I'm happy with all the other steps. But the bug I'm trying to solve is related to link usage.

I will show code snippet bellow here, I'm using react-router-dom v6 latest.

```js
function Search() {
  const music = GetAllSongs();

  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState("");

  const [oldUrl, setOldUrl] = useState("");

  const searchOutput = music
    .filter((data: any) => data.Title.includes(searchInput))
    .slice(0, 7)
    .map((musicData: any, index) => (
      <Link
        key={musicData.id}
        className="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
        to={"/browse/" + musicData.id}
      >
        {musicData.Title}{" "}
      </Link>
    ));

    function handleNotFoundSearch() {
    if (searchOutput.length < 1) {
      return (
        <div className="DocSearch-Dropdown">
          <div className="DocSearch-NoResults">
            <div className="DocSearch-Screen-Icon">
              <svg
                width="40"
                height="40"
                viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                fill="none"
                fill-rule="evenodd"
                stroke="currentColor"
                stroke-linecap="round"
                stroke-linejoin="round"
              >
                <path d="M15.5 4.8c2 3 1.7 7-1 9.7h0l4.3 4.3-4.3-4.3a7.8 7.8 0 01-9.8 1m-2.2-2.2A7.8 7.8 0 0113.2 2.4M2 18L18 2"></path>
              </svg>
            </div>
            <p className="DocSearch-Title text-wrap">
              No results for "<strong>{searchInput}</strong>"
            </p>
            <div className="DocSearch-NoResults-Prefill-List">
              <p className="DocSearch-Help">Try searching for:</p>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <button className="DocSearch-Prefill" type="button">
                    Validation
                  </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <button className="DocSearch-Prefill" type="button">
                    Offcanvas
                  </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <button className="DocSearch-Prefill" type="button">
                    RFS
                  </button>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <span onClick={handleShow}>
        <i className="fa fa-search"></i> Search
      </span>

      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header>
          <div className="input-group searchInput">
            <span className="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">
              <i className="fa fa-search"></i>
            </span>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Search for a song..."
              aria-label="Search"
              aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
              onChange={(e) => setSearchInput(e.target.value)}
              value={searchInput}
            />
          </div>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <div className="list-group searchedData">{searchOutput}</div>
          {handleNotFoundSearch()}
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Search;
```

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <SideNav />

        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />

            <Route path={RoutePath.homePage} element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/browse/:id" element={<PlayMusic />} />
            <Route path={RoutePath.registerPage} element={<SignUp />} />
            <Route path={RoutePath.loginPage} element={<SignIn />} />
            <Route
              path={RoutePath.CreatePlayList}
              element={<CreatePlayList />}
            />
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```js
function PlayMusic() {
  const { id }: any = useParams();
  const music = GetSongById(id);

  function HandleLikeButtonAndAddToPlayList() {
    if (IsUserLoggedIn()) {
      return (
        <div className="LikeAndAddToPlayList">
          <LikeButton songId={id} />
          <EditAndDeleteButton />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  const PlayingMusic = music.map((musicData: any, index) => (
    <div key={musicData.id} className="p-4 rounded-0 songBox">
      <div className="container-fluid shadow-lg">
        <div className="row g-0">
          <div className="col-md-3 mb-md-0">
            <img src={urlCalls.Base + musicData.PhotoCover} />
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-9 ps-md-0">
            <p className="fs-1 Title-lg">{musicData.Title}</p>
            <p className="text-start Owner-name-and-date">
              Drake <i className="fas fa-circle"></i>{" "}
              <span>{musicData.CreatedAt}</span>
            </p>
            <ReactAudioPlayer
              src={urlCalls.Base + musicData.MusicFile}
              autoPlay
              controls
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  ));

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-2">
        <SideBar />
      </div>
      <div className="col-10">
        {PlayingMusic}
        {HandleLikeButtonAndAddToPlayList()}

        <Spinner data={music.length} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have tried using 'usenavigate' but I believe, I can achieve using the link

Comment: Step 7 "Is taking the user to a page that doesn't exist" seems to be where the behavior diverges from expected. Can you clarify what this part actually means? How is the code generating links to pages that don't exist? Can you [edit] to include the relevant code (*i.e. the popup, the link/navigation/etc*) as part of the [mcve]?

Comment: @DrewReese, I have added the whole search components

Comment: I don't see any issue with the links. What are the paths/pages that don't exist? Is the issue that `PlayMusic` isn't updating for the new `id` route path param? Can you also add `PlayMusic` code to the post?

Comment: is working now, but now I'm on a song with id = 1 [link]'http://localhost:3000/browse/1', then while still on that route I searched and then click on a song. each click the route is getting updated [link]http://localhost:3000/browse/3 but not the page

Comment: Can you [edit] the post to include the `PlayMusic` component?

Comment: I have added the PlayMusic component